Inverse function / mapping considering vector multiplication by matrix
Inverse function / mapping considering vector multiplication by matrix
also touches symetric encryption
Consider, there's a simple matrix as a mapping from R3 ➝ R3
R3 ➝ R3: v(3) x M(3,3) = v(3)

⎡ 1 ⎤   ⎡ 4 0 0 ⎤   ⎡ 4 ⎤ 
⎢ 2 ⎥ x ⎢ 0 3 0 ⎥ = ⎢ 6 ⎥  
⎣ 3 ⎦   ⎣ 0 0 2 ⎦   ⎣ 6 ⎦ 

Then it ∃ also an inverse function as a simple mapping matrix from R3 ← R3
v(3) x M(3,3) = v(3) R3 ← R3
                          
⎡ 4 ⎤    ⎡ ¼ 0 0 ⎤     ⎡ 1 ⎤    
⎢ 6 ⎥  x ⎢ 0 ½ 0 ⎥  =  ⎢ 2 ⎥ 
⎣ 6 ⎦    ⎣ 0 0 ⅓ ⎦     ⎣ 3 ⎦   

Suppose, there is a trivial matrix(3x2) as a mapping from R2 ➝ R3
R2 ➝ R3: v(2) * M(3x2) = v(3)

    ⎡ 1 ⎤   ⎡ 4 0 ⎤    ⎡ 4  ⎤
    ⎣ 2 ⎦ x ⎢ 0 3 ⎥  = ⎢ 6  ⎥ 
 ⎢⎢         ⎣ a b ⎦    ⎣ ab ⎦  

Then also there ∃ a matrix(2x3) an inverse function as reverse mapping from R2 ← R3
R3 ➝ R2: v(3) * M(2x3) = v(2)

⎡ 4  ⎤   ⎡ ¼ 0 0 ⎤   ⎡ 1 ⎤ 
⎢ 6  ⎥ x ⎣ 0 ½ 0 ⎦ = ⎣ 2 ⎦
⎣ ab ⎦

Question for all mathematicians:
For which non-trivial matrices does also ∃ an inverse function to / reverse mapping?
Simple Matrices are
a 0 0 0
0 b 0 0
0 0 c 0
0 0 0 d
or
0 0 a 0
0 b 0 0
0 0 0 c
d 0 0 0

Non simple matrices are if there is more then one variable per row or column.
Kind regards,
Heinrich Elsigan.
post scriptum: I know, that when mapping higher to lower dimension, that there's certainly not any inverse mapping, because of loss of information / complexity.
My question is, how big is the numnber of not simple matrices having an inverse mapping (needed for symetric encryption school contest)

Am I understanding correctly that we are talking about square matrices (i.e. $n \times n$). And are you familiar with the concept of the determinant?

Also, for your case of "simple matrices": If $a, b, c, d$ are all $\neq 0$, the simple matrix is always invertible

Thank you for your answer @HyperbolicPDEfriend I was talking about square matrices and when a,b,c,d are all ≠0. I wanted to now if there exist non simple square matrices who are invertible (maybe in some modular arithmetic cases, deutsch: Restklassenring, Restklassenkörper). Do you have an answer?

I see. What exact Restklassenring are you talking about, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ for what $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$?

This might be of interest

please use MathJax to typeset your math. here is a guide.

Yes, Restklassenring is  Z/nZ
fhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n

Your $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^3$ example is not a matrix multiplication. And it looks non-sensical due to the appearance of the product $ab$. I'm quite sure it isn't invertible.

If you want to invert matrices with entries in the residue class ring $\Bbb{Z}_n$, then the usual algorithm will work, if $n$ is a prime number, and the determinant is not divisible by $n$ (in that ring $n=0$, so the algorithm would call for division by zero at some point). See this old example. If $n$ is not a prime, the algoritm may or may not work, depending on luck (something more precise can be worked out). The problem is that you cannot divide by anything that has a common factor with $n$.

See Wikipedia on matrix multiplication.

Basically what I was complaining about is that the number of rows of the matrix $A$ on the left must be equal to the number of columns of the matrix $B$ on the right for the product $AB$ to make sense.
